# plpgsql combine ST_Overlaps and ST_Intersects

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have a question regarding creating a trigger function in postgres with two conditions:

When creating a linestring in QGIS there must be either overlap nor intersect.  So I wrote two functions, each working with either ST_Overlaps or ST_Intersects.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_linesintersecting() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN 
IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
THEN
IF
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT gid
FROM line_layer AS t
WHERE st_intersects(NEW.geom, t.geom)) AS foo)
THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Speicherung abgebrochen: Ueberschneidende Linien!';
RETURN NULL;
ELSE
RETURN NEW;
END IF;
ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
THEN
IF
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT gid
FROM line_layer AS t
WHERE st_intersects(NEW.geom, t.geom)
AND (t.gid <> OLD.gid)) AS foo) > 0
THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Speicherung abgebrochen: Ueberschneidende Linien!';
RETURN NULL;
ELSE RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END IF;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

All I had to to in order to make it detect overlapping was to change the ST_Intersects into ST_Overlaps.  But how can I combine ST_Overlaps and ST_Intersects?

I've tried using the same loop right after each other but only the the first function then is working. Any clues?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Some indentation would improve readability of the code.

Comment: `either overlap nor intersect` do  you mean `either/or` OR `neither/nor`?

Answer (score 1):

what if you use a nested if-else clause?

if they are intersecting, are they also overlapping?

```
if --intersection

    if --both
     then
    else --only intersect
    then

    end if
end if
```